# TSQL - How to get a record satisfies a condition without excluding others that do not

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

It seems pretty simple but I have not touched SQL for years. When I come back , totally stuck with this math. Let say I have 3 tables as below:

Table Name:

```
|NameId| Name |
|------|------|
| 1    | John |
| 2    | Doe  |
| 3    | Brian|
```

Table Tag:

```
|TagId| Tag     |
|-----|---------|
| 1   | Teacher |
| 2   | Engineer|
| 3   | Employee|
```

Table NameTag:

```
|NameId|TagId|
|----  |-----|
|1     | 1   |
|2     | 2   |
|2     | 3   |
|3     | 3   |
```

I want to find **all names along with associated tags by a tag**. E.g. find names with tag Employee (TagId = 3). **I expect result like this:**

```
|NameId|TagId|
|----  |-----|    
|2     | 2   |
|2     | 3   |
|3     | 3   |
```

How can I achieve that in a T-SQL script?

I tried with script below but it always excludes the records 1|1 and 2|2:

```
SELECT *
FROM NameTag    
WHERE TagId = 3
```

Result I do not expect:

```
|NameId|TagId|
|----  |-----|        
|2     | 3   |
|3     | 3   |
```

---

**UPDATE**

Looks like there are many solutions commented below as @plax, @SteveB or @picklerick and some others pointed. I have not had a chance to test all of them but they seem working for me. Thank you all! (early thanksgiving today for me).

By that time, I have also found a solution myself and posted here for reference. Also, @plax pointed out below.

**My solution:**

```
--Get persons that have the tag.
WITH Person_CTE AS
(
    SELECT DISTINCT NameId 
    FROM NameTag
    WHERE TagId = 3
)
-- Looking other tags for the person.
SELECT * 
FROM NameTag nt
JOIN Person_CTE p ON nt.NameId = p.NameId
```

Another solution as @plalx has pointed out that was written very clearly:

1. Find all NameId that have an associated TagId of 3. E.g.

   ```
   SELECT NameId
   FROM NameTag
   WHERE TagId = 3
   ```
2. Find all tags for NameId we found in step #1.

   ```
   SELECT NameId, TagId
   FROM NameTag
   WHERE NameId IN 
       (-- Solution from #1
        SELECT NameId
        FROM NameTag
        WHERE TagId = 3)
   ```

Comment: So you want a resultset with All names for a tag and all the tags for those names?

Comment: So... What are the results that you DO want?

Comment: @SteveB: yes, I do want that.

Comment: @JasonA.Long: I did say in the post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you can't work out a query problem, first break it down into smaller problems you can solve and then merge the smaller solutions together.

1. Find all `NameId` that have an associated `TagId` of `3`. E.g.

   ```
   SELECT NameId
   FROM NameTag
   WHERE TagId = 3
   ```
2. Find all tags for `NameId` we found in step #1.

   ```
   SELECT NameId, TagId
   FROM NameTag
   WHERE NameId IN (
       -- Solution from #1
       SELECT NameId
       FROM NameTag
       WHERE TagId = 3
   )
   ```

If you then run into performance issues you can start from there and try to optimize, but the expressiveness of the query is also important for maintainability.

Comment: I had found a solution myself before I looked back this answer. Plus how you describe to solve the problem. Much appreciated! I also posted my solution above.

Comment: Great! I'm glad you had found a solution. In your solution you dont need the DISTINCT keyword in there given `(NameId, TagId)` pairs are unique already, so you will not have duplicate `NameId` with the condition `WHERE TadId = 3`. I had made the same mistake originally in my answer.

Comment: Actually, there is an Id for table NameTag. I forgot to include it.

Comment: @ThangNguyen I'm not sure I understand how your comment relates to mine? :P

Comment: it does need the DISTINCT keyword because NameId and TagId are not unique. Sorry to not mention that :D.

Comment: Oh ok! So you can tag the same name with the same tag multiple times. That seems weird :P

Answer (score 1):

Or with a correlated subquery instead of a join, just as another way to skin that cat.

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  @NameTag AS nt
WHERE
  EXISTS
(
  SELECT
    1
  FROM
    @NameTag AS n
  WHERE
    n.TagId = 3
    AND n.NameId = nt.NameId
);
```

Results:

```
+--------+-------+
| NameId | TagId |
+--------+-------+
|      2 |     2 |
|      2 |     3 |
|      3 |     3 |
+--------+-------+
```

Comment: This works for me as well. And yes, whenever it works, it's always good. But if I have more choices, I would prefer not choose a nested select. Just IMO. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
Select * from nametag where nameid in(Select nameid from nametag where tagid=3 Group by nameid)
```

Comment: Good, Glad to help!

Answer (score 0):

I think this might be what you are looking for.

```
DECLARE @NameTag TABLE (NameId int, TagId int)

INSERT INTO @NameTag SELECT 1, 1
INSERT INTO @NameTag SELECT 2, 2
INSERT INTO @NameTag SELECT 2, 3
INSERT INTO @NameTag SELECT 3, 3

SELECT a2.*
FROM @NameTag a1
    JOIN @NameTag a2 on a1.NameId = a2.NameId
WHERE a1.TagId = 3 ;
```

Comment: It looks like a very clever solution despite I have not fully tested yet. I will look at it.

Comment: @ThangNguyen It only works because any constraint on a specific single `TagId` is guaranteed to return unique `NameId`s. `a1` will refer to all unique `NameId`s where `TagId = 3` and the `JOIN` essentially acts as the `IN` clause in my answer. I prefer the `IN` clause given it's closer to the semantics of what we want to achieve. Furthermore the solution would return duplicates if the initial condition is changed for something like `TagId IN (2, 3)`. Both solutions should have a similar execution plan and that's a good one as well.

Comment: @plalx  I agree that the IN is a more easily readable solution and I like that.  We just try to avoid it if the results of the inner query can get rather large because we have seen performance issue with it.  We usually replace it with an EXISTS query or a JOIN if possible.  I really wish the more easily readable version of the query was ALWAYS the fastest query.  In this example you are completely right and I should have included it as well as the EXISTS version.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this without a `join`:

```
select nt.*
from (select nt.*,
             sum(case when tagid = 3 then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by nameid) as cnt_3
      from nametag nt
     ) nt
where cnt_3 > 0;
```

Comment: It seems a little bit complex but it works for me. Thanks!

Comment: @ThangNguyen . . . I have no idea why you would think this is complex.

Comment: @ThangNguyen The solution adds the aggregated SUM of rows where `TagId = 3`, partitioned by `NameId`, meaning all rows with the same `NameId` will end up with the same SUM. It then only keeps the rows where the SUM is > 0. It could have been cleaner if `cnt_3` would have been named `include_row` IMO, given it's a bit really: the count would never be greater than 1 in this scenario. It's also a very unintuitive way of solving the problem IMO. Unless it yields any performance benefits that you need I'd keep things simple.

Comment: Thanks for explaining, plalx. 
@Gordon: honestly I have just had an overlook but it's working. Thanks!